How do I use IFS to conditionally apply a percentage?
I'm trying to create a formula that would charge a % to a column depending on another column
Ex. If Column I2 ="Finance" then Multiply Column R2 to K2
OR
If Column I2 ="No" then Multiply Column R2 to F2
This is what I have so far:
=ifs(I2"Financing",K2* 0.04,I2"No",F2* 0.04)

You were just missing the = in your conditionals.
In order to check whether a cell I2 is equal to a value "Finance", you need to use I2 = "Finance" as below:
=ifs(I2="Finance", K2*R2, I2="No", F2*R2)

What would I need to add to make the result 0 if the columns that Im trying to pull from is blank?

@Mr.Carter91 =ifs(I2="Finance", K2*R2, I2="No", F2*R2, I2="", 0)
